how to prove a function exists? (Tao Analysis I 3.5.7)
Question: How does one prove a function exists?
I am a self-teaching beginner, new to proof methods (eg contradiction, contraposition, induction, etc).
I am currently doing Tao's Analysis I ex 3.5.7 which asks us to (i) show a function exists, and (ii) show it is unique.
I have never done proven a function exists before. How do I do it?

My Thinking
I have been learning simple axiomatic set theory, and have learned to show a exists by constructing the desired set using the given axioms - eg axion of replacement, axion of union, axion of selection, etc.
I don't think such an approach works for showing a desired function exists.
I am aware of the necessary properties of functions:

functions always map a given element of a domain to a single element of a codomain (one-to-one, many-to-one, but never one-to-many)
functions have a domain, codomain, and a defined mapping

Is this sufficient to show a function exists?

Other Questions
This post asks the same question but the answer is not clear, or is too advanced for my level.

For reference, the exercise is reproduced here:

Exercise 3.5.7
Let $X$, $Y$ be sets, and let $\pi_{X \times Y \to X}:X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y}:X \times Y \to Y$ be the maps $\pi_{X \times Y \to X} (x, y) := x$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y}(x, y) := y$; these maps are known as the co-ordinate functions on $X × Y$. Show that for any functions $f : Z \to X$ and $g : Z \to Y$, there exists a unique function $h:Z \to X \times Y$ such that $\pi_{X \times Y \to X} \circ h= f$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y} \circ h=g$. (Compare this to the last part of Exercise 3.3.8, and to Exercise 3.1.7.) This function $h$ is known as the pairing of $f$ and $g$ and is denoted $h = ( f, g)$.


Update
I want to avoid the answer being too specific to the exercise, so the following is a simpler example (which I made up).

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which maps as $f(x)=x^2$, show there exists a function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h \equiv f \circ f$.

What would I do to show $h$ exists? Would I do the following?

show $h$ has a domain - in this case $\mathbb{R}$
show $h$ has a codomain - in this case $\mathbb{R}$
make explicit what the mapping is - in this case $h(x)=x^4$
and demonstrate that the definition doesn't contradict the need for functions to map an element of the domain to a single element of the codomain - in this case $h(x)=x^4$ maps to a single element of the domain

Is that all we need to do to show a function exists?

Tao's Definition 3.3.1 on page 40 lays out the steps necessary to show a function exists; so just follow them

The function must be $h(z) = (f(z),g(z))$, so use this for existence.

Hi @balddraz - definiton 3.3.1 states the properties that must hold for a function. Is it sufficient to show that any function I define, exists as a function as long as those properties hold?

HI @copper.hat - I am unsure of this. Simply defining the mapping for a function, eg $h(z)=z^2$ or $h(z)=(f(z), g(z))$ isn't sufficient to prove that function exists .. is it? The linked post gives examples of definitions which don't constitute a function.

The function is given by ${ (z, (f(z),g(z))) \mid z \in Z }$. It should be straightforward to establish that this is a function?

@copper.hat - i'm a beginner so i'm not sure how to establish something is a definition from its mapping definition.

The first thing you have to fact is a set theoretic issue:

Question #1: What must be the format of a function $h : Z \to X \times Y$?

Answer: $h(z)$ must be an ordered pair, the first coordinate of that ordered pair must be an element of $X$, and the second coordinate of that ordered pair must be an element of $Y$. Each of those coordinates must depend on $z$, and so is a function of $z$. Let's choose names for those coordinate functions:
$$h(z) = (h_1(z),h_2(z)), \qquad h_1 : Z \to X, \qquad h_2 : Z \to Y
$$

Question #2: What must $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ be?

Answer: Use the first requirement, which says that $\pi_{X \times Y \to X} \circ h = f$, to get
$$f(z) = \pi_{X \times Y \to X}(h(z)) = h_1(z)
$$
so $h_1$ must be $f$.
Also, use the second requirement, which says that $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y} \circ h = g$, to get
$$g(z) = \pi_{X \times Y \to Y}(h(z)) = h_2(z)
$$
and so $h_2$ must be $g$.
This completes the proof that if the function $h$ exists satisfying those two requirement, then the function $h$ must be given by the formula
$$h(z) = (f(z),g(z))
$$
That completes the proof of uniqueness.
But on top of that it gives you a very strong suggestion of how to prove existence: set
$$h(z) = (f(z),g(z))
$$
Now verify that this function does indeed meet the two requirements. The proof is complete.

Lee - can i ask, which "two requirements" do you mean in your final paragraph?

The two requirements are explicitly stated in my answer. I rewrote my answer to refer to those two requirements in words as "the first requirement" and "the second requirement".

Write the conditions that the hypothetic function will have to satisfy. That will suggest you how to define it, you don't write all this as part of the proof, that's just for you to understand what you need to do.
To prove the existence then you just define the function and prove that the function you defined satisfy the conditions. (You will have proved the existence of the function by exhibiting it).

I'm unclear on the necessary strategy. We can define a function, eg $h(z)=z^2$ or $h(z)=(f(z),g(z))$ or anything else. To show it exists - do we simply show that the given definition doesn't contradict the properties of a function as per def 3.3.1 in Tao's book - eg they map elements of the domain to a single element of. the codomain, they have a domain, and have a codomain?
